# Cannot access Puppet Learning VM

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, puppet

I have set up puppet learning VM on VirtualBox. I can ssh into it with:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

However, the guide says to do `facter ipaddress`, and ssh into the ipaddress that outputs. I get `10.0.2.15`.

If I try that ipaddress, it does not work. I want to get it to work.

Also, I am supposed to be able to access the Puppet gui from https://10.0.2.15 and am not able to do that. I think the two problems are related.

I have 3 adapters set up. 1. NAT, 2. host only adapter, 3. bridged network.

For #1, I have port forwarding set up (am not able to ssh without it).

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:44:00:48
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe44:48/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15892 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1232127 (1.1 MiB)  TX bytes:2062554 (1.9 MiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:72:B7:0E
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:14:93:EE
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:322880 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:322880 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:233893154 (223.0 MiB)  TX bytes:233893154 (223.0 MiB)
```

Answer (score 3):

**NICs**

I don't see any IP assigned to your NICs except eth0. I assume this learning VM is based on centos, please configure your network adapters correctly first.

check:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

This is no puppet or virtualbox issue.

**port forwarding**

Accessing `https://10.0.2.15` will not work, this is an internal NAT network IP. Please create an entry for your VMs NAT Adapter under Port-Forwarding, just map Host Port 10443 to guest port 443. If you try to access `https://localhost:10443` in your browser you should reach the service running on this VM and listening on port 443.(Check if the service is running and the firewall/iptables is open on all needed ports).

Answer (score 1):

Patrick is right. The configuration within the CentOS box is strange.

It's working for me under windows but on my Ubuntu system I had big trouble setting up the Training VM.

My Tip: just add 22 and 80 port forwordings in your virtualbox. 
Change -> Network -> Adapter 1 -> Port-Forwarding -> add

Protokol: TCP | Host-Port: 2222 | Guest-IP: 10.0.2.15 | Guest-Port: 22 
-> you may connect now by:

> ssh localhost -p 2222 -l root

also:

Protokol: TCP | Host-Port: 8081 | Guest-IP: 10.0.2.15 | Guest-Port: 80
-> you may access the questguide via:

> http://localhost:8081